# how do you keep two versions of project open in GIT

Tags: git

I am used to regular source control systems such as TFS, SVN etc. I'm trying to learn GIT. I have run into a need where I need to have two project solutions open from two different branches. In TFS, no problem, just go to the individual folders and open the solutions. You can have two of them open and compare them.

How do I do this in GIT. From what I know, the same set of files get changed when I switch branches in the GIT console. So, i switch to branch1 and open the solution, then i switch to branch2 in the console, what happens then? Can I open the project again and still have two versions open. This is using Visual studio for .net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would make two Git *clones* in separate directories. Different clones are entirely separate, and they can be pointing at different branches with no conflicts.